# how to set separate link styles in separate divs in HTML

Tags: css, html, hyperlink, href

I have two divs in a web page (say view_1 and view_2). I want the styles of the links in each div to be different. Let's say the styles of the links are as follows:

style of links in div view_1:

```css
a:link {
    color: #CB4C2F;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
    color: #CB4C2F;
}
a:active,
a:hover {
    color: #B60A00;
}
```

style of links in div view_2:

```css
a:link {
    color: #B5B5B5;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
    color: #808080;
}
a:active,
a:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

In the page, I want to specify only the div in use. I do not want to specify a style for the links; the links should adopt the styles from the div in which they exist. How may this be accomplished?

Answer (score 1):

Add classes to your div's

View_1

```css
.view_1 a:link {
    color: #CB4C2F;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.view_1 a:visited {
    color: #CB4C2F;
}
.view_1 a:active,
.view_1 a:hover {
    color: #B60A00;
}
```

View_2

```css
.view_2 a:link {
    color: #B5B5B5;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.view_2 a:visited {
    color: #808080;
}
.view_2 a:active,
.view_2 a:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```